# Easiest way to extend GHC with new deriving capabilities?

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass, deriving

I would like to teach GHC to derive new typeclasses. Is it possible to do this externally without using `Generic` or TemplateHaskell? Like, with source plugins or something similar. So I can write:

```
data MyType = ...
    deriving MyTypeClass
```

**UPDATE:** Relevant GHC ticket with discussion:

- https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/15650

Comment: What is the difference between a TemplateHaskell script and a "source plugin"?

Comment: @DominiqueDevriese Syntax sugar. I would to write `data MyType = ... deriving (Eq, Ord, MyClass)` instead of `data MyType = ... deriving (Eq, Ord); deriveMyClass ''MyType`.

Comment: Why not use `Generic`? If you implement a default `Generic` interface you can use the `DeriveAnyClass` extension to get the syntax you want.

Comment: `Generic` introduces performance overhead. Because you first convert to `Generic` representation and only then you work on that `Generic`. This is the reason why people use `TemplateHaskell` to derive `ToJSON/FromJSON` instances instead of using `DeriveAnyClass`.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr Sorry, I don't see why it's preposterous. Could you, please, elaborate more on the cons of this approach? GHC doesn't know how to generate efficient instances for my typeclass if I write `deriving (MyClass)`. So there should be a way to teach GHC how to do so. Of course, I can fork GHC and add my logic there (in theory), but it's much better if this functionality can be added externally to the compiler in the opt-in way via some plugin for example. Writing this a compiler plugin allows to work with GHC AST directly instead of using `TemplateHaskell`.